# Perl: Strings not escaping backslashes

Tags: perl, string, escaping

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong with such a simple statement. The problem occurs on the line:

`$this->_validate_hash($hashref->{$key}, $schemaref->{$key}, $path . (ref($hashref->{$key}) ? $key . "/" : "\\\@$key"),  $errors);`

So I want things to end with `/path/to/some/\@attribute`. However, what I'm getting at the moment is `path/to/some/\\@attribute`. I tried various combos for the last part including `'\\' . '@' . $key` or `'\@' . $key` or `'\\@' . $key` but I still can't escape the backslash. Is this some quirk in perl strings that I'm not aware of? Thanks.

Comment: Works for me. Can you reproduce with the minimum code possible?

Comment: Ok, Now I feel kinda stupid. It does work, but it seems like it doesn't because when I print the hash, the values are printed within single quotes. So `"/path/to/some/\@attribute"` is rendered  as `'key' => 'path/to/some/\\@attribute'`. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is *not* a simple statement; it is split over two lines and contains all sorts of stuff.  This achieves the same result, as near as I can see (and assuming `$xpath` is not used elsewhere in your script):

```
my $xpath = $path . (ref($hashref->{$key}) ? $key . "/" : "\\\@$key");
$this->_validate_hash($hashref->{$key}, $schemaref->{$key}, $xpath, $errors);
```

However, it is more nearly readable - still not particularly easy, but much more readable than the original.

Your problem child can be reduced, it seems, to:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $key  = "attribute";
my $path = "/path/to/some/";
my $localpath = $path . "\\\@$key";

print "Key:   $key\n";
print "Path:  $path\n";
print "Local: $localpath\n";
```

That code works cleanly:

```
Key:   attribute
Path:  /path/to/some/
Local: /path/to/some/\@attribute
```

So, either I've got a different Perl (this was 5.12.1 on Linux x86/64) or there is something different in your setup.  Given that we don't have all the hashes etc, it will be hard to get at it - but you should break down your problem in an analogous way.